# WLST Bean error when trying to set target server

Tags: python, mbeans, wlst, workmanagers

I am trying to create a work manager by running my python code using WLST. In my python code when trying to set target server for a work manager with **cmo.addTarget(bean)**, it is throwing the following error:

> ======= Creating a WorkManager name for WM_AgreementOps11 =======
>
> MBean type WorkManager with name WM_AgreementOps11 has been created successfully.
>
> No stack trace available. This Exception occurred at Mon
>   Feb 04 13:13:51 IST 2019. javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException:
>   com.bea:Name=WM_AgreementOps11,SelfTuning=DefaultDomain,Type=WorkManager:SelfTuning
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\bin\WorkManagerSetUp.py",
>   line 70, in main
>       cmo.addTarget(bean) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A non-null value expected
>
> Saving all your changes ... Saved all your changes successfully.  WorkManager
>   Created...

Below is the code:

```
import sys
import os
import jarray
import dircache
import traceback
from java.io import File
from java.io import FileInputStream
from java.lang import String

#=======================================================================================    
myPropertyFile = "workManagerProperties.properties" 

print '======= Reading Property File and Connecting to Server ========'
propInputStream = FileInputStream(myPropertyFile)
configProps = Properties()
configProps.load(propInputStream)

#=======================================================================================
# connection() Definition
#=======================================================================================
def connection():
    print '===> Connecting as '+ username + ' To WebLogic URL ' + url + '...'
    try:
        connect(configProps.get("username"), configProps.get("password"), url)
    except WLSTException:
        print '==> Error Connecting to The URL ' + url
        CancelEdit('y')
        exit()

print '==== Exiting Because Of Connectivity Error ===='

#===== THE SERVER URL ==================================================================
url=configProps.get("protocol") + '://' + configProps.get("host") + ':' + configProps.get("AdminPort")
connection()
#=======================================================================================
wmcount=configProps.get("workManager.count")

print '======= Number of Work Managers to be set: ' + wmcount + ' ======='

#=======================================================================================
# START EDITING WORK MANAGER
#=======================================================================================

def main():

    print ('================== inside main ==================') 
    DSCOUNT=1
#=======================================================================================    
    while(DSCOUNT<=int(wmcount)):
        edit()
        startEdit()
        ServerName=configProps.get("ServerName")
        domainName=configProps.get("domainName")
        workManagerName=configProps.get("workManagerName."+str(DSCOUNT))    
        MaxThread=configProps.get("MaxThread."+str(DSCOUNT))
        MinThread=configProps.get("MinThread."+str(DSCOUNT))    
        maxThreadConstraintName=configProps.get("maxThreadConstraintName."+str(DSCOUNT))    
        minThreadConstraintName=configProps.get("minThreadConstraintName."+str(DSCOUNT))    
#==================================== WORK MANAGER ========================================
        print '======= Target Server for Work Managers: ' + ServerName + ' ======='    
        print '======= Creating a WorkManager name for ' + workManagerName + ' ======='   
        cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/')
        try:
            create(workManagerName,'WorkManagers')
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
        cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/' + workManagerName)
        bean = getMBean("/Servers/"+ ServerName)
        try:
            cmo.addTarget(bean)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
        save()
        print ' WorkManager Created...'

        print '======= Creating MaxThreadsConstraint ======='
        cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/MaxThreadsConstraints/')
        try:
            create(maxThreadConstraintName,'MaxThreadsConstraints')
        except Exception:
            print 'Issue in Creating MaxThreads exiting'
        cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/MaxThreadsConstraints/' + maxThreadConstraintName)
        bean = getMBean("/Servers/"+ ServerName)
        try:
            cmo.addTarget(bean)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
        set('Count',MaxThread)
        save()
        print ' MaxThreadsConstraints Created...'

        print '======= Creating MinThreadsConstraint ======='
        cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/MinThreadsConstraints/')
        try:
            create(minThreadConstraintName,'MinThreadsConstraints')
        except Exception:
            print 'Issue In Creating MinThreads '
        cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/MinThreadsConstraints/' + minThreadConstraintName)
        bean = getMBean("/Servers/"+ ServerName)
        try:
            cmo.addTarget(bean)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
        set('Count',MinThread)
        save()
        print ' MinThreadsConstraints Created...'

        print '======= Assigning the MaxThreadConstraint to the WorkManager ======='
        cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/' + workManagerName)
        bean=getMBean('/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/MaxThreadsConstraints/' + maxThreadConstraintName)
        cmo.setMaxThreadsConstraint(bean)

        print '======= Assigning the MinThreadConstraint to the WorkManager ======='
        cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/' + workManagerName)
        bean=getMBean('/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/MinThreadsConstraints/' + minThreadConstraintName)
        cmo.setMinThreadsConstraint(bean)

        save()
        activate(block="true")
        print '==> WorkManager Creation Finished ... Please Double Check from AdminConsole...'
        DSCOUNT=DSCOUNT+1
    disconnect()

main()
```

Comment: are you sure that "bean" is not null (None) ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment...Yes....I ensured that bean is not null.....because I ran the code for only one work manager (i.e the above code is not under While loop) and it worked perfectly fine. Once I put the code under while loop , as I have to set multiple work managers, this issue started appearing.

Comment: Can your share the complete code including the loop ?

Comment: I have updated above with the entire code

Comment: Can you try to have just one edit session and not a session per loop iteration ?

Comment: I tried by putting ** edit() ** outside while loop. But still i am getting same error

Comment: The issue was in bean = getMBean("/Servers/"+ ServerName), "/Servers/"+ ServerName is not in string format , so it was returning null. I resolved it by adding targetServ="/Servers/"+ServerName and then replacing bean as bean = getMBean(str(targetServ))

Comment: so i was right when i asked "are you sure that "bean" is not null (None) ?"  ;o)

Comment: Yes you were right......At that time i only checked by printing "/Servers/"+ ServerName which gave output . When i tried printing getMBean("/Servers/"+ ServerName), it gave as null............